# Таблицу HTML загрузить в таблицу БД MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Имеется таблица HTML в которую заносятся данные из БД. И такая же таблица HTML на странице администратора только редактируемая. Задача состоит в том чтобы после внесения изменений в таблицу в админке, после нажатия на кнопку, все данные изменялись в имеющейся таблице в БД.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарю)

Comment: Задача поставлена, решайте. Благодарить нас не за что.

Comment: Нужен только правильный вектор в каком направлении мне действовать. Думаю данные ячеек заносить в переменные и отправлять их на сервер?!

Comment: Другим образом вы взаимодействие с сервером не организуете.